# Toggle Visibility of All Data Validation Input Messages in a Table

Tags: vba, excel, validation

I have an Excel spreadsheet that is designed to facilitate the bulk creation of new user accounts in an information system I help administer. Due to the fact that we have had issues in the past with people providing invalid data in various columns, I have setup data validation rules and, in particular, data validation input messages for the entire table to help guide the spreadsheet users in providing the correct data.

A problem I foresee cropping up is there are a total of 16 fields that a user is expected to fill out, some users may be annoyed at the input message boxes that pop up each time they select a cell in the table.

My question is this: **Is there away to hide all of the data validation input messages in my table using VBA?**

Using the record macro feature and some references in msdn.microsoft.com I have come up with the following code that I think is on the right track:

```
Sub test()

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DataEntry").ListObjects("Data").Range.Select

    With Selection.Validation

        .ShowInput = False

    End With

End Sub
```

Right now I get the following error:

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Any help that you could provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could validate the data through VBA instead of using Data Validation, this way you could check each of the fields and then output a message that highlights all the things that need fixing...

Comment: @Xabier thank you for the comment and I see what you are proposing but I think that would add a layer of complexity that I am not sure I want to invest the time in implementing.